# Evenly formatted Ouput

Tags: linux, awk, grep

In linux, I am pulling up some data with a grep command and the below is what I am getting, column 1 can contain a number or string and column2 also the same

```
123 ABC
456 DEF
GHI 789
```

I need an output like below column1 with numbers and column2 with string or vice versa

```
123 ABC
456 DEF
789 GHI
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you need. What columns should be swapped and how can we know if they need to be swapped or not? Kusalananda asked you several questions. Please read them and provide the answers because we cannot help you without that information.

Comment: There's an edit attempt from another account named Suman. If it's you than please see [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) After you regain ownership of the question you will be able to edit it freely.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ print (/^[A-Z]/?$2 FS $1 : $0) }' infile
```

if a line was started with a uppercase ASCII alpha, swap the columns, else print the line unchanged.

or in short:

```
awk '/^[A-Z]/{ $0=$2 FS $1 }1' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer it works only if it contains only 2 columns

```
awk '/^[A-Z]/{m=$1;$1=$2;$2=m}1' filename


output

awk '/^[A-Z]/{m=$1;$1=$2;$2=m}1' filename
123 ABC
456 DEF
789 GHI
```